# Regex catch word at the start and end of a UITextView

Tags: regex, swift

I'm trying to catch when a word is used in a `UITextView`. I've got it working for words in the interior of the view.

The problem is when the word is first or last in the view. 
My code so far:

```
private func filteredTermFor(_ word: String) -> String {
    let punctuationFilter = "([\\A|\\W|\\d|\\z| ])"
    let wordInParens = "(\(word))"
    return punctuationFilter + wordInParens + punctuationFilter
}
```

I checked and found I should use `^` for the start of input and `$` for the end of input. When I add either of these, for example:

```
"([^|\\A|\\W|\\d|\\z| ])"
```

they don't seem to have any effect when the word in question is the first or last in the view.

*For the sake of being verbose with my question, the return value from the function above is being used as `searchTerm` in this:

```
    func highlightedTextInString(with searchTerm: String, targetString: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: targetString)
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchTerm, options: .caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: targetString.utf16.count)
        for match in regex.matches(in: targetString, options: .withTransparentBounds, range: range) {
            let fontColor = UIColor.red
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: fontColor, range: match.range)
        }
        return attributedString
    } catch _ {
        print("Error creating regular expression")
        return nil
    }
}
```

** Edit **
Since this was marked as a duplicate
The question this was reported a duplicate of does not cover edge cases when the word is typed next to a punctuation mark or digit without spaces.
For example:
`.word` , `word9` , `?word?`

Comment: Your "punctuationFilter" is a mess, and does not do what you think you do. Zero-width assertions put inside a character class lose their special meaning. Adding `^` to the `[...]` at the start makes it a negated character class that matches any char other than the defined chars/sets in the class. You want to search for a whole word, use word boundaries, `\b`. `let punctuationFilter = "\\b"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "a mess" is probably putting it kindly as I'm not familiar with RegEx. There are basically three situations I'm trying to cover ` word ` , `(X)word ` and ` word(X)` In these cases, X could be a punctuation or digit.

Comment: Please check the solutions in the linked thread. Else, try `return "(?<!\\p{L})(\(word))(?!\\p{L})"`. This means *match `word` if not preceded nor followed with a letter*. I closed the question because it sounds like you need to match whole words. Please edit it to include *exact word boundary requirements*.

Comment: ok. thanks for your help.

Comment: So, does it mean you need to match a `word` when it is in between word boundaries or digits? Like `return "(?<![^\\W\\d])(\(word))(?![^\\W\\d])"`? Or does the expression from the above comment work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the expression above works. It's really just a case of me needing to learn more about regex. I'm not aware of many of the expressions at this point.

Thanks again for the help. Sorry for creating a duplicate.

Comment: Aha, I see. If the `"(?<!\\p{L})(\(word))(?!\\p{L})"` works, it means I closed the question with a correct dupe as the accepted answer contains `"(?<=[^A-Za-z]|^)[A-Za-z]+(?=[^A-Za-z]|$)"` solution that is almost equivalent (it only supports ASCII letters, `\p{L}` matches all Unicode letters). If `"(?<![^\\W\\d])(\(word))(?![^\\W\\d])"` works better for you, I will reopen to include an answer.

Comment: If you do, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `([^|\\A|\\W|\\d|\\z| ])` is a capturing group (`(...)`) containing  a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches a single char defined inside it. The `^` after `[` makes the class a *negated* one, and it matches any char but the one(s) defined in the set. So, `[^|\\A|\\W|\\d|\\z| ]` matches a single char other than `|` (it is no longer an alternation operator inside a character class), `A` (the `\` in front is not considered, is omitted), a non-word char, a digit, `z` and space. It [effectively matches](https://regex101.com/r/nQVUnR/3) `_` and any letters other than `A` and `z`.

You state that the words you need to match may occur within word boundaries or digits.

You may use

```
return "(?<![^\\W\\d])(\(word))(?![^\\W\\d])"
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nQVUnR/2).

Here, `"(?<![^\\W\\d])"` is a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is NOT immediately preceded with a character other than a non-word and a digit char. This sounds cumbersome, but the main point here is that `[^\W\d]` matches the same texts as `\w` excluding digits (`\w` matches letters, digit, and `_`. So, `"(?<![^\\W\\d])"` makes sure there is a start of string or a non-letter and non-`_` char right before the *word*. If you allow a word to match after `_`, just use `(?<!\\p{L})` (where `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter).

The `"(?![^\\W\\d])"` is a negative lookahead that makes sure there is an end of string or a non-letter and non-`_` (there can be punctuation, symbols and digits) immediately to the right of the word. Again, if you want to match a word if it is *followed* with `_`, you may replace this lookahead with `"(?!\\p{L})"` (just no letter after the word is allowed).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation and the link. I've definitely got some studying to do!